# Как удалить в каталоге только те файлы, которые содержат четный номер?

Tags: shell, terminal

Доброго времени суток.

В каталоге есть 100 файлов с именами от a0.txt до a99.txt.

Не подскажете, какой командой я могу удалить только те файлы, в имени которых содержится четное число?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`rm *[02468]\.txt*`